# Integrability of the supremum of a sum of Birkhoff averages

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a probability space and $T:X\rightarrow X$ an ergodic transformation. The Birkhoff averages of a function $\phi:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are defined by
$$
\phi_n(x)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \phi\circ T^j(x)
$$

Birkhoff ergodic theorem says that $\phi_n(x) \rightarrow c\in \mathbb{R}$ for a.e $x\in X$, where $c$ is the spacial average, under the hypothesis $\phi \in L^1(\mu)$.

Is it true, under same hypothesis, that $\varphi(x)= \sup_n \phi_n(x)$ ( which is finite a.e., by what was said), is integrable? Under some more assumptions ( like $\phi_n \geq 0$, for example)?

Comment: Using maximal ergodic theorem we can assert that $\lambda\mu\{\varphi(x)\geqslant\lambda\}\leqslant\mathbb E[\chi_{\{\varphi(x)\geqslant\lambda\}}|\phi|]$ hence if $\phi\in\mathbb L^{1+\delta}$ it would be ok. Maybe we can construct a counter-example using Rokhlin tower, I will think on it.

Comment: I believe its true, Davide, but I don't know how to prove. I will explore your idea using maximal ergodic theorem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the paper by Ornstein (1971) [A remark on the Birkhoff ergodic theorem](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256052821) shows that in this context, a necessary and sufficient condition for $\varphi$ to be integrable is the integrability of $\max\{0,|\phi|\cdot\log|\phi|\}$.